# angular 5 (from 4) upgrade fails unit test with error error TS2339: Property 'loaded' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, typescript

I updated angular 4 to angular 5 and get errors while running tests:

The error is:

```
t.ts(20,11): error TS2339: Property 'loaded' does not exist on type '{}'.src/test.ts(28,25): error TS2339: Property 'context' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/test.ts(32,11): error TS2339: Property 'start' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

I can see test.js has typescript compilation error. My typescript version is 2.4.2

Here is the test.ts file:

```
import './polyfills.ts';

import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

// Unfortunately there's no typing for the `__karma__` variable. Just declare it as any.
declare var __karma__: {};
declare var require: {};

// Prevent Karma from running prematurely.
__karma__.loaded = function () {};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
// Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
__karma__.start();
```

Do I need to modify test.ts file after the upgrade? If yes what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

>>>

```
// Unfortunately there's no typing for the `__karma__` variable. Just declare it as any.
declare var __karma__: {};
```

The message says you need to declare it as `any`. So declare it as `any` ...